# ElasticSearch - символы "е" и "ё"

Tags: elasticsearch

Всем привет!
Использую elasticsearch 7.2.1.
В индексах есть слова с символами "ё" вместо "е".
Вопрос - как можно при поиске символа "е" выдавать и первый и второй вариант?

Answer (score 1):

Тут есть пример с анализаторами и char_filter
http://it-blackcat.blogspot.com/2019/10/elasticsearch-no-difference-what-to-find.html

Вот пример из моего приложения:

```
analysis:
        char_filter:
            eCharFilter:
                type: mapping
                mappings: ['Ё=>Е', 'ё=>е']
        analyzer:
            fullWordAnalyzer:
                type: 'custom'
                tokenizer: 'whitespace'
                filter:
                - 'lowercase'
                - 'unique'
                char_filter:
                - 'eCharFilter'
```