# ElasticSearch - сортировка, из-за кодировки буква "Ё" возвращается первой

Tags: elasticsearch

```
Всем привет, пишу проект для себя и использую там ElasticSearch 7.10.1. При попытке отсортировать поле возвращает значения начинающиеся с букв Ё, А, Б, В, Г, Д, Е и так далее.
Пробовала писать скрипт в блоке sort запроса, но из-за этого он стал в разы медленнее выполняться.
Так же была похожая проблема с поиском. Её решил кастомный анализатор похожий на это https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1010649/elasticsearch-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D1%91. Но как оказалось с сортировкой он не помогает.
```